# Guardar Imagen en carpeta reduciendo su tamaño

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagen

Tengo una imagen cargada en un `fileUpload`, lo que necesito es guardar ese imagen reduciendo su tamaño a **100kb**(Aproximado no tiene que ser exacto) en una carpeta de la aplicación.

Hasta ahora llevo  desarrollado el siguiente código:

```
  protected void btnSubirImagen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {

            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName).ToLower();
            List<String> allowsExtension = new List<String> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
            Byte[] Archivo = null;
            Byte[] a = null;
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
            {
                Archivo = reader.ReadBytes(fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength);
                System.Drawing.Image img = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(Archivo));
                System.Drawing.Image imgRezice = resizeImage(img, 50, 50);

                a = ImageToByteArray(imgRezice);

                if (allowsExtension.Contains(fileExtension) && Archivo.Length <= 1000000)
                {
                    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
                    string nombreArchivo = fileUpload.FileName; 
                    string ruta = "~/Content/images/ProfileImages/" + g + fileExtension;
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(ruta), a);
                    picture.ImageUrl = ruta;
                    this.User.GuidImagen = ruta;
                }
    }
 public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imageIn.Save(ms, imageIn.RawFormat);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Image resizeImage(System.Drawing.Image img, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b);

        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        g.Dispose();

        return (System.Drawing.Image)b;
    }
```

El problema de esto es que al querer convertir nuevamente a un **`ByteArray`** a la imagen, me salta la siguiente excepción:

> System ArgumentNullException: 'Valuecannot be null. Parameter name:
>   encoder'.

Entiendo que esto debido a que pierde el formato(**png**, **jpg**, **etc**) luego del resize pero no logro volver a dárselo.

También estoy dispuesto hacer esto de otra forma si es que existe. Pero el objetivo es guardar la imagen cargada en un **FileUpload** en un tamaño reducido en una carpeta de la aplicación.

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve una necesidad parecida a la tuya, lo resolví basándome en esta respuesta de so.com de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161873/reduce-image-size-c-sharp).
Dónde utiliza GetEncoderInfo tendrías que modificarlo para pasar además el del .png y el .jpg.
Poco más que añadir, la respuesta de @Pratik es muy clara.